# Planeta Terra em particulas com THREE js

Tags: html5, 3d, webgl, three.js

tenho procurado por toda internet a dias mas não encontro nenhum tutorial explicativo ou algo perto disso , sou novo em THREE js  e gostaria de  fazer  o planeta terra em em forma de partículas  igual a essa imagem mas só as particulas sem as linhas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu vi muitos projetos prontos com código aberto para uso  mas são muito complexos  eu gostaria de saber só como criar as particulas em torno da esfera  simulando o planeta terra para aprendizado , alguém pode me dar uma luz de como começar ?  grato a toda ajuda.